# Table of Function Pointers in .text section

Tags: ida, disassembly

In the disassembly of user32.dll, I see tables of function pointers like the one below in .text section. It doesn't look like vftable or switch/case table. Can you please give any insight about what this table is for?

```
.text:6BA87530 off_6BA87530    dd offset sub_6BAD4C1E  
.text:6BA87534 dword_6BA87534  dd 0                    
.text:6BA87538                 dd offset sub_6BA890C6
.text:6BA8753C                 align 10h
.text:6BA87540                 dd offset sub_6BAD4B0A
.text:6BA87544                 align 8
.text:6BA87548                 dd offset sub_6BAD4730
.text:6BA8754C                 align 10h
.text:6BA87550                 dd offset sub_6BA890C6
.text:6BA87554                 align 8
.text:6BA87558                 dd offset sub_6BA890C6
.text:6BA8755C                 align 10h
.text:6BA87560                 dd offset sub_6BA890C6
.text:6BA87564                 align 8
.text:6BA87568                 dd offset sub_6BACCCB6
.text:6BA8756C                 align 10h
.text:6BA87570                 dd offset sub_6BAD5EE1
.text:6BA87574                 align 8
.text:6BA87578                 dd offset sub_6BAE82EE
.text:6BA8757C                 align 10h
.text:6BA87580                 dd offset sub_6BA9D3D5
.text:6BA87584                 align 8
.text:6BA87588                 dd offset sub_6BAE2428
.text:6BA8758C                 align 10h
.text:6BA87590                 dd offset sub_6BAE83F1
.text:6BA87594                 align 8
.text:6BA87598                 dd offset sub_6BAA9760
.text:6BA8759C                 align 10h
.text:6BA875A0                 dd offset sub_6BA9F560
.text:6BA875A4                 align 8
.text:6BA875A8                 dd offset loc_6BA8DA5B
.text:6BA875AC                 align 10h
.text:6BA875B0                 dd offset sub_6BA890C6
.text:6BA875B4                 align 8
.text:6BA875B8                 dd offset sub_6BA87CA1
.text:6BA875BC                 align 10h
.text:6BA875C0                 dd offset sub_6BAD41C5
.text:6BA875C4                 align 8
.text:6BA875C8                 dd offset sub_6BA893E9
.text:6BA875CC                 align 10h
.text:6BA875D0                 dd offset sub_6BA9B419
.text:6BA875D4                 align 8
.text:6BA875D8                 dd offset sub_6BA87B11
.text:6BA875DC                 align 10h
.text:6BA875E0                 dd offset sub_6BAEFB8A
.text:6BA875E4                 align 8
.text:6BA875E8 off_6BA875E8    dd offset sub_6BAD4BFD
```

The start and end addresses (`off_6BA87530, off_6BA875E8`) are referenced by code snippets like

```
.text:6BA8FFE8                 push    eax
.text:6BA8FFE9                 push    offset off_6BA87530
.text:6BA8FFEE                 push    eax
.text:6BA8FFEF                 push    offset off_6BA875E8
.text:6BA8FFF4                 call    ds:RtlInitializeNtUserPfn
```

or

```
.text:6BA9D84F                 mov     esi, ds:off_6BA87530[eax*8]
.text:6BA9D856                 mov     [ebp+var_40], esi
.text:6BA9D859                 mov     eax, ds:dword_6BA87534[eax*8]
.text:6BA9D860                 mov     [ebp+var_3C], eax
.text:6BA9D863                 jmp     loc_6BA87A7C
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
Adding the code snippets of functions referred to by first two addresses:  `sub_6BAD4C1E, sub_6BA890C6`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you show an example of what the table entries are *pointing at*? That might gives us a clue (i.e. regular function, thunk, runtime info...). For example, the code might be registering exception thunks.

Comment: the first one is USER32!ScrollBarWndProcA the second one is USER32!DefWindowProcA  doesn't your ida pick up the symbol file for user32.dll ? if it doesnt load the user32.dll in windbg as a dump file windbg -z user32.dll load the symbol and compare addresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RtlInitializeUserPfn  `rep movsds` **(memcpy())** those address to ntdll!_NtUserPfn  (most of the addresses are Windowsproc buttonproc callbacks

what windows version are you on iirc these functions weren't implemented until win 8 
see below

**0:000> u ntdll!NtdllDispatchDefWindowProc_W l1**

```
ntdll!NtdllDispatchDefWindowProc_W:
77e039f4 ff25ac80e377    jmp     dword ptr [ntdll!NtUserPfn+0xac (77e380ac)]
```

**0:000> ln poi(77e380ac)**
    ntdll!UninitUser32Proc ()

**0:000> uf ntdll!UninitUser32Proc**

```
ntdll!UninitUser32Proc:
77e03aa4 6896a0da77      push    offset ntdll! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string' (77daa096)
77e03aa9 6a00            push    0
77e03aab 6a00            push    0
77e03aad e884dff7ff      call    ntdll!DbgPrintEx (77d81a36)
77e03ab2 83c40c          add     esp,0Ch
77e03ab5 cc              int     3
77e03ab6 680d0000c0      push    0C000000Dh
77e03abb 6aff            push    0FFFFFFFFh
77e03abd e8062efaff      call    ntdll!NtTerminateProcess (77da68c8)
77e03ac2 33c0            xor     eax,eax
77e03ac4 c3              ret
```

**0:000> da 77daa096**

```
77daa096  "User32 init not called"
```

windows 7 user32!DllInit routine fills the array itself

```
user32!InitializeNtdllUserPfn:
77d2d787 b86606d277      mov     eax,offset user32!ImeWndProcW (77d20666)
77d2d78c a36096d777      mov     dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x100 (77d79660)],eax
77d2d791 a30091d777      mov     dword ptr [user32!g_pfnImeWndProcW (77d79100)],eax
77d2d796 b9063fd677      mov     ecx,offset user32!EditWndProcW (77d63f06)
77d2d79b 33c0            xor     eax,eax
77d2d79d c7056495d7770449d377 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x4 (77d79564)],offset user32!ButtonWndProcW (77d34904)
77d2d7a7 c7058895d7779de0d577 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x28 (77d79588)],offset user32!ComboBoxWndProcW (77d5e09d)
77d2d7b1 c705ac95d777ae0dd477 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x4c (77d795ac)],offset user32!ListBoxWndProcW (77d40dae)
77d2d7bb c705d095d777c15bd477 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x70 (77d795d0)],offset user32!DefDlgProcW (77d45bc1)
77d2d7c5 890df495d777    mov     dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x94 (77d795f4)],ecx
77d2d7cb c7051896d777ae0dd477 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0xb8 (77d79618)],offset user32!ListBoxWndProcW (77d40dae)
77d2d7d5 c7053c96d777df14d477 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0xdc (77d7963c)],offset user32!MDIClientWndProcW (77d414df)
77d2d7df c7058496d7778b3ad377 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x124 (77d79684)],offset user32!StaticWndProcW (77d33a8b)
77d2d7e9 c7055c97d7777d50d277 mov dword ptr [user32!gDefaultClasses+0x1fc (77d7975c)],offset user32!DefWindowProcW (77d2507d)
77d2d7f3 c7053891d777f8b5d377 mov dword ptr [user32!g_pfnEditWndProcA (77d79138)],offset user32!EditWndProcA (77d3b5f8)
77d2d7fd 890d2091d777    mov     dword ptr [user32!g_pfnEditWndProcW (77d79120)],ecx
77d2d803 40              inc     eax
77d2d804 c3              ret
```

while some other user32.dll > win7 calls a forwarded import in ntdll

```
user32!InitializeNtdllUserPfn:
00000001`80022e98 4c8bdc          mov     r11,rsp
00000001`80022e9b 4883ec38        sub     rsp,38h
00000001`80022e9f 4983631000      and     qword ptr [r11+10h],0
00000001`80022ea4 4983630800      and     qword ptr [r11+8],0
00000001`80022ea9 4983631800      and     qword ptr [r11+18h],0
00000001`80022eae 488d05eba50000  lea     rax,[user32!pfnClientWorker (00000001`8002d4a0)]
00000001`80022eb5 bab8000000      mov     edx,0B8h
00000001`80022eba 49c743f058000000 mov     qword ptr [r11-10h],58h
00000001`80022ec2 4c8d0537a60000  lea     r8,[user32!pfnClientW (00000001`8002d500)]
00000001`80022ec9 488d0df0a60000  lea     rcx,[user32!pfnClientA (00000001`8002d5c0)]
00000001`80022ed0 448bca          mov     r9d,edx
00000001`80022ed3 498943e8        mov     qword ptr [r11-18h],rax
00000001`80022ed7 ff155b520800    call    qword ptr [user32!_imp_RtlInitializeNtUserPfn (00000001`800a8138)]
```

with windbg you can retrieve all the wndprocs that are memcpied thus using some script like below

```
.for(r $t0=0 ; @$t0 < (60+c0+c0) ; r $t0 = @$t0+8) { .printf "%y %y\n" , user32!pfnClientWorker+@$t0 , poi(user32!pfnClientWorker +@$t0) }
```

which would get you result like this (read with the disassembly posted above of a random(winblue) user32.dll that implements the forwarded import

```
user32!pfnClientWorker (00000001`8002d4a0) user32!ButtonWndProcWorker (00000001`8001c760)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x8 (00000001`8002d4a8) user32!ComboBoxWndProcWorker (00000001`80060c38)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x10 (00000001`8002d4b0) user32!ListBoxWndProcWorker (00000001`80077fa0)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x18 (00000001`8002d4b8) user32!DefDlgProcWorker (00000001`8001ebf0)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x20 (00000001`8002d4c0) user32!EditWndProcWorker (00000001`80031354)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x28 (00000001`8002d4c8) user32!ListBoxWndProcWorker (00000001`80077fa0)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x30 (00000001`8002d4d0) user32!MDIClientWndProcWorker (00000001`80036400)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x38 (00000001`8002d4d8) user32!StaticWndProcWorker (00000001`8001f0a0)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x40 (00000001`8002d4e0) user32!ImeWndProcWorker (00000001`80008e14)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x48 (00000001`8002d4e8) user32!DefWindowProcWorker (00000001`80008ef0)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x50 (00000001`8002d4f0) user32!CtfHookProcWorker (00000001`80005d44)
user32!pfnClientWorker+0x58 (00000001`8002d4f8) 90909090`90909090
user32!pfnClientW (00000001`8002d500) user32!ScrollBarWndProcW (00000001`8005f6cc)
user32!pfnClientW+0x8 (00000001`8002d508) user32!DefWindowProcW (00000001`80002d60)
user32!pfnClientW+0x10 (00000001`8002d510) user32!MenuWndProcW (00000001`8005f574)
user32!pfnClientW+0x18 (00000001`8002d518) user32!DesktopWndProcW (00000001`8005f138)
user32!pfnClientW+0x20 (00000001`8002d520) user32!DefWindowProcW (00000001`80002d60)
user32!pfnClientW+0x28 (00000001`8002d528) user32!DefWindowProcW (00000001`80002d60)
user32!pfnClientW+0x30 (00000001`8002d530) user32!DefWindowProcW (00000001`80002d60)
user32!pfnClientW+0x38 (00000001`8002d538) user32!ButtonWndProcW (00000001`8001c6cc)
user32!pfnClientW+0x40 (00000001`8002d540) user32!ComboBoxWndProcW (00000001`80060ad8)
user32!pfnClientW+0x48 (00000001`8002d548) user32!ComboListBoxWndProcW (00000001`80077ed4)
user32!pfnClientW+0x50 (00000001`8002d550) user32!DefDlgProcW (00000001`8001eb7c)
user32!pfnClientW+0x58 (00000001`8002d558) user32!EditWndProcW (00000001`800312c4)
user32!pfnClientW+0x60 (00000001`8002d560) user32!ComboListBoxWndProcW (00000001`80077ed4)
user32!pfnClientW+0x68 (00000001`8002d568) user32!MDIClientWndProcW (00000001`8003634c)
user32!pfnClientW+0x70 (00000001`8002d570) user32!StaticWndProcW (00000001`8001f050)
user32!pfnClientW+0x78 (00000001`8002d578) user32!ImeWndProcW (00000001`80008da0)
user32!pfnClientW+0x80 (00000001`8002d580) user32!DefWindowProcW (00000001`80002d60)
user32!pfnClientW+0x88 (00000001`8002d588) user32!fnHkINLPCWPSTRUCTW (00000001`80003da0)
user32!pfnClientW+0x90 (00000001`8002d590) user32!fnHkINLPCWPRETSTRUCTW (00000001`80012c40)
user32!pfnClientW+0x98 (00000001`8002d598) user32!DispatchHookW (00000001`80003d20)
user32!pfnClientW+0xa0 (00000001`8002d5a0) user32!DispatchDefWindowProcW (00000001`8000ed34)
user32!pfnClientW+0xa8 (00000001`8002d5a8) user32!DispatchClientMessage (00000001`800038f0)
user32!pfnClientW+0xb0 (00000001`8002d5b0) user32!MDIActivateDlgProcA (00000001`80080100)
user32!pfnClientW+0xb8 (00000001`8002d5b8) 90909090`90909090
user32!pfnClientA (00000001`8002d5c0) user32!ScrollBarWndProcA (00000001`8005f6b0)
user32!pfnClientA+0x8 (00000001`8002d5c8) user32!DefWindowProcA (00000001`8000ad38)
user32!pfnClientA+0x10 (00000001`8002d5d0) user32!MenuWndProcA (00000001`8005f558)
user32!pfnClientA+0x18 (00000001`8002d5d8) user32!DesktopWndProcA (00000001`8005f11c)
user32!pfnClientA+0x20 (00000001`8002d5e0) user32!DefWindowProcA (00000001`8000ad38)
user32!pfnClientA+0x28 (00000001`8002d5e8) user32!DefWindowProcA (00000001`8000ad38)
user32!pfnClientA+0x30 (00000001`8002d5f0) user32!DefWindowProcA (00000001`8000ad38)
user32!pfnClientA+0x38 (00000001`8002d5f8) user32!ButtonWndProcA (00000001`8005c620)
user32!pfnClientA+0x40 (00000001`8002d600) user32!ComboBoxWndProcA (00000001`80060970)
user32!pfnClientA+0x48 (00000001`8002d608) user32!ComboListBoxWndProcA (00000001`80077e40)
user32!pfnClientA+0x50 (00000001`8002d610) user32!DefDlgProcA (00000001`8006a3d8)
user32!pfnClientA+0x58 (00000001`8002d618) user32!EditWndProcA (00000001`8006ec64)
user32!pfnClientA+0x60 (00000001`8002d620) user32!ComboListBoxWndProcA (00000001`80077e40)
user32!pfnClientA+0x68 (00000001`8002d628) user32!MDIClientWndProcA (00000001`80081450)
user32!pfnClientA+0x70 (00000001`8002d630) user32!StaticWndProcA (00000001`80086268)
user32!pfnClientA+0x78 (00000001`8002d638) user32!ImeWndProcA (00000001`8008dad0)
user32!pfnClientA+0x80 (00000001`8002d640) user32!DefWindowProcA (00000001`8000ad38)
user32!pfnClientA+0x88 (00000001`8002d648) user32!fnHkINLPCWPSTRUCTA (00000001`8008c850)
user32!pfnClientA+0x90 (00000001`8002d650) user32!fnHkINLPCWPRETSTRUCTA (00000001`8008c790)
user32!pfnClientA+0x98 (00000001`8002d658) user32!DispatchHookA (00000001`8008bea0)
user32!pfnClientA+0xa0 (00000001`8002d660) user32!DispatchDefWindowProcA (00000001`8008be84)
user32!pfnClientA+0xa8 (00000001`8002d668) user32!DispatchClientMessage (00000001`800038f0)
user32!pfnClientA+0xb0 (00000001`8002d670) user32!MDIActivateDlgProcA (00000001`80080100)
user32!`string' (00000001`8002d678) 4c4e4e49`576d6d49
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using Windows 10. Does it mean that RtlInitializeNtUserPfn takes the start and end addresses of an array and copy the callback function addresses from that array to _NtUserPfn? If yes, how would that array/data structure look like in the source code of user32.dll? My goal is to understand and distinguish among various tables (vftable/jump table/exception handler table) of function pointers in a dis-assembled binary.